# Выполнение динамически добавленного скрипта

Tags: javascript, dom

Динамически добавляю скрипт в документ.

1. Если добавляю текстом (`script.text = "...";`), он запускается сразу же.
2. Если добавляю внешний скрипт (`script.src = "...";`), он запустится после того, как закончит выполняться мой.

Т.е. в примере внизу я получу "0 1 2" и "3 3 3" соответственно (в 1.js та же строка - "document.body.innerHTML += i").

```
<body>
  <script>
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "1.js";
    //  script.text = "document.body.innerHTML += i";
      document.body.append(script);
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Почему так задумано (я это где-то пропустил)? И как мне запустить 1.js сразу же после добавления?

Comment: добавь содержимое `1.js`, или одна строка это все, что находится в этом файле?

Comment: @Grundy да, просто эта же строка

Answer (score 0):

при добавления скрипта с урлом, браузер обращается на этот урл и выполняет его ассинхронно вашему коду. 
это можно увидеть в деббагере браузера Chrome -> Network -> XHR.

сразу выполнить удаленный скрипт невозможно в данном контексте.

Comment: это я понимаю, вопрос как раз в том точно ли невозможно и почему? и почему в таком случае не работает script.async=false;, например

Comment: вы отдаете управление DOM и говорите ему "Загрузика мне этот скрипт". Скрипт может грузится минуту, могут быть проблемы в сети. Как только вы отдали управление, он его сам разруливает. Вы можете добавить callback, как только скрипт загрузился - onload. Но это будет ассинхронно вашему коду. async аттрибут говорит о том, чтобы не ждать отработки других скриптов. т.е они перестанут выполняться  последовательно, как указано в HTML. тут он не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить [async](http://htmlbook.ru/html/script/async), тоесть браузер при возможности запускает скрипт асинхронно. Это означает, что указанный в атрибуте src файл будет выполняться без ожидания загрузки и отображения веб-страницы

Comment: async не работает, и, если я ничего не путаю, значит он всё-таки диаметрально противоположное